# Retraction to the boundary

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am a student studying Algebraic topology. While studying, I have a question following:

> Q1. Let $U$ be the entire space, and let $X\subset U$ be an open and path-connected set whose closure is compact, and $U-X$ is also path connected, $A$ be boundary of $X$. I think there are no retraction or deformation retraction of $X$ onto $A$. Is it true?

I have no idea how to prove this, but I have intuition, if there exist, I think it would be somewhat non-continuous.

edit: I edited some conditions.

Comment: These would better be split into two separate questions.

Comment: okay let me do it.

Comment: Restriction or retraction? In any case, consider $X$ which is a singleton.

Comment: I mean retraction.  I edited my question. @MoisheKohan

Comment: If $X\subset \Bbb R^n$ is open and compact,  then $X = \varnothing$

Comment: I feel like you're thinking the right ideas, but you need to tighten up your question. By the [Heine–Borel theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem), a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it's both closed and bounded. But you also want your set $X$ to be open. A set that is both closed and open, together with its complement in $\mathbb{R}^n$ forms a separation, contradicting the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected. In other words, no set $X$ as you've described it actually exists.

Comment: @SammyBlack Sorry. I think I made a mistake because I have been waken up whole night to study... I just wanted to say open, and bounded set. Thank you for criticizing me.

Comment: This is true if you assume $\partial X$ is sufficiently regular in some sense. If $\overline{X}$ is a manifold

Comment: It does not appear that you know the meaning of the word "retraction" in topology. Check your textbook.

Comment: @Didier Open and compact?

Comment: @PaulFrost There was an edit. The original question was asking about $X$ open and compact.

Comment: What is "universal" space? Also forget about being a retract, the boundary of $X$ is not even a subset of $X$, if $X$ is not closed to begin with. Anyway if $U=[0,\infty)$ and $X=[0,1)$ then all the conditions are satisfied but the boundary of $X$ is $\{1\}$ which clearly is a deformation retract of both $U$ and $\overline{X}$.

Comment: @freakish Thank you. That was what I exactly wanted.

Comment: The question was now edited to the point of becoming trivial. A good question along these lines would be: is there $K\subset R^n$, a 
  compact subset with nonempty interior that admits a retraction to its boundary?

Comment: @MoisheKohan In what way is the current revision trivial? Changing notation slightly, we basically have a cover of some generic space $U$ by two closed path connected sets $A,B$ with $A\cap B=\partial A=\partial B$ and want to know if $A$ can (deformation) retract onto $\partial A$. I don't see why that is an easy question to answer

Comment: @FShrike: Actually, in two ways. One is that a retraction is defined only to a subset of $X$, and $A$ is not. Thus, the answer is trivially negative. There is a way to correct the current question by requiring $X$ to be compact with nonempty interior. But the question then has a trivial positive answer. I leave it to you to find such examples, it takes just a few minutes.

Comment: One can also require $X$ to be compact, equal to the closure of its interior. Trivial examples exist for this version as well.

Comment: @MoisheKohan As in, trivial examples of compact $X$ with nonempty interior that *do* retract to their boundary?

Comment: @FShrike: exactly.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah, like with Freakish's example, some trick like $[0,1]$ retracting to $\{1\}$ in $[0,\infty)$ because, relative to $[0,\infty)$, $\{0\}$ is not a boundary point. Are there examples where we take $U$ to be the whole Euclidean space?

Comment: Right. As for subsets of Euclidean spaces, see my suggested question above. I think such retracts do not exist. The proof is most likely by using Chech cohomology, but  I am not sure.

Comment: @FShrike: upon further examination, indeed, there are no retractions in this setting. I will add an answer later on (cannot do it from a phone).

Comment: @MoisheKohan In the unfortunate event that this question is closed, I will repost your suggested reframing of it as a question and hope to have your answer published somewhere. I likely know too little algebraic topology to properly understand it but it would be interesting

Comment: @FShrike: Could you ask a new question? I do not like answering an unclear question, especially if my answer is to a different question....

Comment: @MoisheKohan https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4792713